# Request assistance writing a PS script to search for a list of files (path + filename) against all Windows servers in my environment

Tags: windows, powershell

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Create a PS script to run from a single Admin machine, but search against C$ on all Windows servers in AD.
2. Search for a specific list of paths\filenames that I provide.
3. If ANY of the specific list of paths\filenames are found on a server, THEN output the server name, and paths\filenames to a *.CSV file titled "Badfiles.csv" on the Admin machine.

Was trying to build from the following syntax but admittedly my old brain is not good at this stuff, and I've only specified a single file here - how do I refer to a list of multiple paths\files? Thank you for helping an old lady out. :)

```
$name= gc env:computername
$computers= get-content -path C:\Windows\Temp\v.bat
$csvfile = "c:\temp\$badfiles.csv" 
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    "\$computer\C$\" | Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*.bat"
}
```

Comment: the `Resolve-path` cmdlet will accept an array of full file names & return an array of those that resolved. if you use `-ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'` it will skip the not-there items and only show you the ones that were found. ///// the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet can run a scriptblock on every computer in a list _at the same time_ and give you the results back on the calling system.

Comment: please, add a sample - the 1st three or four lines - from your CSV file to your Question & wrap it in code formatting so that it will be easy to read. that will make any proposed improvement to your code much more on-point. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a list of items whether those are files or computer names you will need to use what is called an Array.

You can create an array in many ways, in your case it might best to create a list in a txt file and afterwards in Powershell you read the list contents using `get-content`, save the result in a variable and it will automatically be saved as an array!

Then iterate through each of them using what is called a `foreach` loop, that basically lets you take each of the items in the array and do something with it, then move to the next item and so on until every item has been dealt with.

Now the most important part of what you want to achieve is not clear. Let me explain.

To check if a file exists you can use `test-path`. That will return `true` or `false` and you can then act upon the result of that. You need to define an exact path and name of a file to check for this to work.

If you don't know the exact names and paths of files that need to be checked, you can use Get-ChildItem similarly as you have done in the code you provided. The caveat here is that you have to narrow down the scope of the file search as much as you can. In your example you search for the `.bat` file extension on the whole machine and that can result in some issues. A typical C drive will have hundreds of thousands if not millions of files and folders. Parsing all of them can take a long time.

So this is an important distinction to understand and what causes confusion for me is that you say in `"2. Search for a specific list of paths\filenames that I provide..."` yet in the code you use `Get-ChildItem` to get all files instead of providing a list of filenames.

Further I will assume you have a list of filenames with exact known paths.

Now in your given code I can see you have found some of the right commands but they need to be arranged differently to produce the results you need.

Please review this example code that might help you further:

Example `ComputerList.txt` file content(list of computer hostnames to check):

```
computer1
serverXYZ
laptop123
```

Example `FileList.txt` file content(List of files to check for in each of the above computers):

```
c:\temp\virus.bat
c:\games\game.exe
c:\Pictures\personal.jpg
```

Now the PowerShell code:

```
# Gets the list of items from TXT files and saves them as arrays in variables
$ComputerNames = Get-Content 'c:\temp\ComputerList.txt'
$FileList = Get-Content 'c:\temp\FileList.txt'

# Define the path and name of CSV report
$BadFiles = "c:\temp\badfiles.csv"

# Define the foreach loop that will iterate through each hostname in computer list
foreach($computer in $ComputerNames){
    # Define foreach loop that will iterate through each file in the list and test their path in the current computer in the current iteration
    foreach($file in $FileList){
        # Test the path of the current file in the loop and append the CSV file if it was found
        # Convert the file path to C$ share path
        $file = $file -replace("c:","c$")
        # Define path of file to test
        $FileToTest = "\\$computer\$file"
        if (test-path $FileToTest -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
            # This block will run only when a bad file has been found
            # This part can be tricky but it is used to make sure we properly format the current bad file entry when we append it to the resulting CSV file
            $BadFile = "" | select Computer,File

            # Save information about current computer
            $BadFile.computer = $computer

            # Save information about current file
            $BadFile.file = $file

            # Append the entry to an array of found bad files
            $BadFileList += $badfile 

        }
    }
}
# When done iterating through every computer and file, save the results in a CSV file
$BadFileList | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $BadFiles
```

The above is a full code snippet you can test and run in your environment. First please create the two TXT files and make sure you run PowerShell with the appropriate permissions to access the `C$` network shares of the servers.

The snippet should work but I have not tested it myself. Let me know if there are any errors.

Please test and feel free to ask if you have any follow up questions.